# INDEX / MATCH with Boolean LKP_value & AND LKP_Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I require a INDEX/MATCH which returning a value from a TRUE Match criteria. I have used an AND for the LKP_Array as I have 2 Boolean tests. I have checked and it should be returning the value in yellow '2017 - KP1'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the array you are looking up in, as well as the expected output?

Comment: I have added the array & the expected output is the '2017 - KP1' in yellow

Comment: I don't think you can use AND in an array formula - I think you need to multiply two boolean criteria. https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Thanks @JerryJeremiah that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the newest version of Excel you can just use `FILTER`.

```
=FILTER('KP Cohorts'!$E$36:$E$4000, 
(('KP Cohorts'!$B$36:$B$4000=Sheet1!B33)*
('KP Cohorts'!$CD$36:$CD$4000>0)))
```

If not, I believe you can do something like the below (untested, since I don't have older versions):

```
=INDEX('KP Cohorts'!$E$36:$E$4000, 
MATCH(2,
--('KP Cohorts'!$B$36:$B$4000=Sheet1!B33)+--('KP Cohorts'!$CD$36:$CD$4000>0)),1)
```